# When trying to access callback URL -> Google Drive message: Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, callback

First off, apologies for the layman's terms - very much a novice.

I'm in the process of creating an `Oauth1a` workflow to access an external service (which uses `Oauth1a`) from Google scripts (since I'm accessing an external service and not the other way around I don't need to use `Oauth2`).

I have successfully navigated the process up to the point where the external service (after my app issuing a request token, getting the necessary info back, and then asking for authorization) attempts to access the app callback URL. The service's URL takes the following format:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/d/<SCRIPT_ID>/usercallback?oauth_token=<ENCODED_TOKEN>&oauth_verifier=<VERIFIER>
```

However, the callback URL does not open and the callback function is not invoked and I receive the message:

> Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address
> and try again.

I have tried/checked:

1. Not logged on to other Google accounts. Other accounts have been removed.
2. Tried through incognito tab - same error message.
3. Published as a web app - same error message (though I should not have to publish as a web app for this usage, based on what Google says)
4. Removed the `/usercallback...` part from the URL the service has issued - this opens my Apps Script home page, but does nothing else.
5. Compared the callback URL logged by my script with the callback URL that the service tried to access (same, excluding the `Oauth...` part of course.) Also checked the headers in Chrome - can't see anything unusual.

I should mention that I'm using the following script (copied it into scripts and using it as an "internal" library in the "foreground" script): https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth1

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **dev/exec** seccion on the URL.

https://script.google.com/macros/d/<SCRIPT_ID>/**exec**/usercallback?oauth_token=<ENCODED_TOKEN>&oauth_verifier=

Comment: thank you for your response, but this unfortunately did not fix the issue: deployed as web app (which should not be necessary fir just a callback), allowed access by anyone, regenerated service URL and manually added the exec part where you suggested it, but still the same error message.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the "d" part in the URL. It is not always "/macros/d/", it could be "/macros/s/" or something like that. Be sure to copy the most recent URL of the project.

Comment: tried the "s". Now I get: Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes. I doubt this is it, unfortunately

Comment: It is not always "d" or "s". Copy the URL generated by your Google Apps Script project when implemented, which includes the "s"/"d" (or any other letter) + ID + exec/dev. Something like this: https://script.google.com/macros/s/abc123/dev.

Comment: Thank you - this solved it: 1) publish script as web app 2) set callback URL to https://script.google.com/macros/s/<WEB_APP_DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec/usercallback

A doGet function placed into the script

function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}

... shows the parameters (now need to pass into script).

I'm still surprised though. Based on everything I've seen, I should not have to publish this as a webapp. I have a suspicion that somehow the callback does not like the oauth1a authorization, but have no way of confirming this.